# Soap API and email templates

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap

I'm cancelling order via Magento Soap API, for some reason emails sent are using default/default templates/skin etc. Is it possible to select which template/skin is used for emails?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using the `salesOrderCancel` SOAP-Method.
As I can see from the [Magento SOAP API Documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.cancel.html), there are no attributes for setting an option to send e-mails or not or specifiying the scope.

So out of the box, this seems not possible.